# PHP7 /e modifier no longer supported (помогите в конкретном случае - preg_match_all)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php7

Перевожу сайт на php7.4 с php5.6, пофиксил уже много несоместимостей, но пока упёрся вот в такое:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in ...Parser.php on line 196
>
> PHP Warning:  Invalid
> argument supplied for foreach() in ...Parser.php on line 197

Понятно что вторая ошибка прямое следствие первой, вопрос как раз насчёт неё.
Как модифицировать следующий код, чтобы результат его работы был в точности какой и раньше, но при этом без использования /e?

```
  public static function links($text)
  {
    $inline = (@$mode == 'url') ? ')' : '';
    $scheme = (@$mode == 'url') ? '[a-z\d+\-.]' : '[a-z\d+]'; // avoid automatic parsing of "word" in "last word.http://..."
    $regexps = array(
      "[a-z]$scheme*:/{2}(?:(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})+|[0-9.]+|\[[a-z0-9.]+:[a-z0-9.]+:[a-z0-9.:]+\])(?::\d*)?(?:/(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)*(?:\?(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@/?|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)?(?:\#(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@/?|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)?",
      "www\.(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})+(?::\d*)?(?:/(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)*(?:\?(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@/?|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)?(?:\#(?:[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'($inline*+,;=:@/?|]+|%[\dA-F]{2})*)?"
    );
    foreach ($regexps as $re)
    {
      preg_match_all('#(^|[\n\t (>.])('.$re.')#ie', $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
      foreach ($m as $u) $text = str_replace($u[2], '[url]'.$u[2].'[/url]', $text);
    }
    return $text;
  }
```

Спасибо!

P.S. Код не мой, я даже не знаю что конкретно он на сайте делает и почему в 5.6 такого предпреждения не было, хотя там /e уже считался Deprecated.

Comment: Удалите его - Из документации: Замечание:

Этот модификатор (е) используется только в функции preg_replace(), в других PCRE функциях он игнорируется.

Comment: А вы не знаете случайно, так было всегда во всех версиях php или это начиная с какой-то он стал игнорироваться в других функциях кроме preg_replace() ?

Comment: Нет, не знаю на сто процентов. Но это фраза из старого мануала. Так что, возможно, что всегда. По сути похоже

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58) в комментариях: действительно, в данной функции модификатор `/e` бессмысленный, и его наличие на её работу похоже никак не влияет (во всяком случае пока не замечено изменений в поведении соответствующей части сайта), так что решение и ответ на вопрос:

Нужно заменить

```
preg_match_all('#(^|[\n\t (>.])('.$re.')#ie', $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

на

```
preg_match_all('#(^|[\n\t (>.])('.$re.')#i', $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

И всё.

Благодарю!